# How do I retain TextBox line breaks in Winforms after assigning text to a string variable?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, richtextbox

I have a WinForms app with a multi-line textbox. This displays and retains (after loading from the DB) line break characters fine.

However if I assign the TextBox.Text value to a string variable and then re-assign the variable back to the TextBox.Text property, the line break characters are lost and replaced with a square character (can't past them here as they just paste as a line break!)

I've tried:

```
Replace("\n",vbcrlf)
```

but to no avail.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

UPDATE**

I haven't managed to fix this but have worked around it by avoiding the variable assignment. I now pass a reference to the RichTextBox and directly manipulate the text there. Note that this seems specific to the RichTextBox as I don't see the issue with a normal TextBox.

Comment: Generally this type of problem arise when you set Multiline=false.

Comment: Yes, but Multiline is set to true in this case.

Comment: "\n" doesn't mean anything special in vb.net, only C#.  Use vbCr, vbLf or vbCrlf.

Comment: Please show the actual code you are using (or some sample code that duplicates the problem) because just assigning to the text property of a textbox should not remove any characters at all!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Replace("\n"' vbcrlf), you need, to use either Replace(vblf, vbcrlf), or Replace(vbcr, vbcrlf).

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea:
How about fixing “\r\n” instead of “\n”?

Answer (score 0):

Are you transforming the string anyway? Since something like this:

```
    Dim s As String = TextBox1.Text
    TextBox1.Text = s
```

works well.

Comment: That's exactly the logic I'm using, nothing any more complicated.

Comment: Do you have special encoding set in the textbox?

Answer (score 0):

```
textBox.AppendText("your new text" & Environment.NewLine)
```