# how to do a newline while printing a RichTextbox in a .txt file in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to print in a .txt file the text I am printing in a `RichTextBox`.

The problem I am having is that in the richtextbox I am using vbCrLf each time I want to print a newline:

```
 Dim msg As String = selectedMarker.ToolTipText & " - Position Request: " & vbCrLf
 ShowMessageColor(msg, Color.Yellow)

Public Sub ShowMessageColor(msg_ As String, color_ As System.Drawing.Color)
    Console.ConsoleRichTextBox.SelectionStart = Console.ConsoleRichTextBox.Text.Length
    Dim oldColor = Console.ConsoleRichTextBox.SelectionColor
    Console.ConsoleRichTextBox.SelectionColor = color_
    Console.ConsoleRichTextBox.AppendText(msg_ & vbCrLf)
    Console.ConsoleRichTextBox.SelectionColor = oldColor

    Console.ConsoleRichTextBox.ScrollToCaret()
End Sub
```

Here I am printing a message in a specific color in the richtextbox (I am changing the color because there are different items that print message and with this I can identify who is sending me messages)

To print in the .txt file, I an using the following:

```
If System.IO.File.Exists(SavePathConsoleLog) Then
        log = Console.ConsoleRichTextBox.Text.ToString & vbCrLf
        File.AppendAllText(SourcePathConsoledLog, log)
    Else
        File.Create("C:\NTGS\BMS\BMS_v6\BMS_v2\ConsoleLog.txt").Dispose()
        log = Console.ConsoleRichTextBox.Text.ToString & vbCrLf
        File.WriteAllText(SourcePathConsoledLog, log)
    End If
```

And this is what I am obtaining:

```
Alakran4 - Vehicle Damages Report: Alakran4 - Position Request: Alakran4 - Vehicle and Tripulation State: AO3 - Position Request: AO3 - Target State
```

All in the same line...

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Maybe can someone help me? I think that using vbCrLf, it must do it. I have used it before and I had no problems. The information in my richtextbox appears like this:

```
Alakran4 - Vehicle Damages Report: 

Alakran4 - Position Request: 

Alakran4 - Vehicle and Tripulation State: 

AO3 - Position Request: 

AO3 - Target State
```

Thanks for any help you could give me!

Comment: Assuming you've read Magnus' answer: Windows' Notepad doesn't interpret `Lf` as a line break. That's why you seem to get everything in one line, but actually you aren't.

Answer (score 1):

A RichTextBox doesn't have `vbCrLf` as linebreaks, it has `vbLf`.

To get the desired output, you should do something like:

```
log = Console.ConsoleRichTextBox.Text.Replace(vbLf, vbCrLf) & vbCrLf
If System.IO.File.Exists(SavePathConsoleLog) Then
    File.AppendAllText(SourcePathConsoledLog, log)
Else
    File.Create("C:\NTGS\BMS\BMS_v6\BMS_v2\ConsoleLog.txt").Dispose()
    File.WriteAllText(SourcePathConsoledLog, log)
End If
```

Somewhat similar to [How do I retain TextBox line breaks in Winforms after assigning text to a string variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637092/how-do-i-retain-textbox-line-breaks-in-winforms-after-assigning-text-to-a-string)

**edit:** The following example illustrates this:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        RichTextBox1.Text = "Line 1" & vbNewLine & "Line 2"
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseDown
        Debug.Print("Newline: " & RichTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(vbNewLine))
        Debug.Print("Cr: " & RichTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(vbCr))
        Debug.Print("Lf: " & RichTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(vbLf))
    End Sub
End Class
```

When run, it gived the following output:

```
Newline: -1
Cr: -1
Lf: 6
```

Comment: No, a `RichTextBox` doesn't use `Lf` linebreaks. It follows Windows' behaviour and uses `CrLf`.

Comment: Really? Not in my Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10 anyways.. It just shows vbLf between the lines.

Comment: That's strange, because if you check the [**source code**](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TextBoxBase.cs.html#37cabfde1449b18f) for the setter of the `RichTextBox.Lines` property you'll see that if you pass it an array of strings it will concatenate them with `\r\n` (`CrLf`): `text.Append("\r\n");`.

Comment: Can't help you there.. I just call 'em as I see 'em.. :)

Comment: Wow! I just tested it, and you are right: A `RichTextBox` does only use `Lf` for line breaks. It's rather odd that it behaves that way because Windows itself actually use `CrLf` for line breaks. The normal `TextBox` control uses `CrLf` though.

Comment: A little thing I noticed in your answer though (not related to our discussion): You don't need the `File.Create(...)` call. `File.WriteAllText()` will already create the file for you if it doesn't exist.

Comment: I copied the original example, which had a mix of variables and static strings. Since I didn't know which was correct, I didn't fix it.

Comment: Oh right, sorry. I didn't notice it was the OP's code. I'm using Stack Overflow from my phone so the code is a little harder to read.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your advices!

I couldn't achieve this, so finally I decided to write the lines in the .txt file at the moment I am writing the line in the RichTextbox. Something like this:

```
Dim msg As String = item.ToolTipText & " - Position Request: " & vbCrLf
ShowMessageColor(msg, Color.Yellow)

Public Sub ShowMessageColor(msg_ As String, color_ As System.Drawing.Color)
    Console.ConsoleRichTextBox.SelectionStart = Console.ConsoleRichTextBox.Text.Length
    Dim oldColor = Console.ConsoleRichTextBox.SelectionColor
    Console.ConsoleRichTextBox.SelectionColor = color_
    Console.ConsoleRichTextBox.AppendText(msg_ & vbCrLf)
    timestamp = DateTime.Now
    log = timestamp & vbTab & vbTab & msg_ '& vbCrLf
    File.AppendAllText(SourcePathConsoledLog, log)
    Console.ConsoleRichTextBox.SelectionColor = oldColor

    Console.ConsoleRichTextBox.ScrollToCaret()
End Sub
```

With this, I write in the same function the text in the Richtextbox and in the file.

Thakns for your help! Was very useful!